# Making Rectangles to work like RadioButtons using Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button, expression-blend, rectangles

Suppose I have n number of rectangles.
I want them to behave such that when I click on any rectangle it should be filled white and all other should be filled with black color.

I know that I can create a style. But while creating style I can tell the trigger that fill the rectangle with black color but how can I say that fill all the remaining rectangles with white color.

Can anyone suggest me?
I want just a small hint.

Comment: why do you need to use rectangles? why not `RadioButton` templated as rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make rectangles work like `RadioButtons`, make `RadioButtons` look like rectangles.
I would suggest to use `RadioButton` instead and change template to make it look like rectangle. Then you can trigger change of background based on `RadioButton.IsChecked` property. This way `RadioButton` will take care of tick/untick operation and trigger background change in other `RadioButtons` in the same group.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
               <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black" x:Name="PART_Border">
                  <ContentPresenter/>  
               </Border> 
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                       <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                   </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use your `RadioButton` like this:

```
<RadioButton>
   <RadioButton.Content>
      <!-- content to be displayer inside border -->
   </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Thank You. Its a good suggestion from you. Now I have a rectangle and image inside it. Both of them are binded into a ViewBox. Now I have 5 such viewboxes. I have tried to convert them to RadioButtons. Here I was successful. But the problem occurs now. I want all the five RadioButtons to have different images.

Comment: @user2524507 updated my answer. Basically put `ContentPresenter` inside `Border` and when you add `RadioButton` specify its content to be your image

Answer (score 1):

You've answered the question yourself. Take two radio buttons and try editing the template. Basically when you'll have the close look at the template you will find an ellipse with a dot whose visibility gets toggled off on mouse click

Instead of having the ellipse you can have a rectangle/border with some thickness and set its background color on mouse click

Comment: Thank You. Its a good suggestion from you. Now I have a rectangle and image inside it. Both of them are binded into a ViewBox. Now I have 5 such viewboxes. I have tried to convert them to RadioButtons. Here I was successful. But the problem occurs now. I want all the five RadioButtons to have different images.